# Circular Dependancy in Angular-Material Dialog Module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, circular-dependency

I'm working with Angular 8 and I have a login modal with a link to the signup modal, and vice-versa. Both modals are opened from the authService. The problem is that the authService needs a reference to the login and signup components in order to open them. I just can't find a way to avoid the circular dependency there.

**I searched google and stackoverflow and the best solution I found was to deactivate circular dependency warnings in the angular.json file, which is not the solution I'm looking for.** I shorten the 3 relevant files to only show the relevant code. It's all working fine, I just want to get rid of the error message and not face any unexpected problems later on and I try to find out what the correct way is of doing this.

```
export class AuthService {
  loginModalRef: MatDialogRef<LoginComponent>;
  signupModalRef: MatDialogRef<SignupComponent>;

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog
    ) {}

  closeLoginModal(): void {
    this.loginModalRef.close();
  }

  closeSignupModal(): void {
    this.signupModalRef.close();
  }

  openLoginModal(): void {
    if (this.signupModalRef) {
      this.closeSignupModal();
    }
    this.loginModalRef = this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, {panelClass: 'login-dialog'});
  }

  openSignupModal(): void {
    if (this.loginModalRef) {
      this.closeLoginModal();
    }
    this.signupModalRef = this.dialog.open(SignupComponent, {panelClass: 'signup-dialog'});
  }
}


export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

//when user clicks on 'Signup instead'
  openSignupModal() {
    this.authService.openSignupModal();
  }
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

// when user clicks on 'Login instead'
  openLoginModal() {
    this.authService.openLoginModal();
  }

// when user clicks on 'Terms of Services' the modal closes
  closeSignupModal() {
    this.authService.closeSignupModal();
  }
}
```

This is the error message:

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>       src\app\auth\auth.service.ts -> src\app\auth\login\login.component.ts -> src\app\auth\auth.service.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>       src\app\auth\login\login.component.ts -> src\app\auth\auth.service.ts -> src\app\auth\login\login.component.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>       src\app\auth\signup\signup.component.ts -> src\app\auth\auth.service.ts ->
>   src\app\auth\signup\signup.component.ts

Comment: Ignore them IMO; in your case they wont cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably restructure your app a bit here so that your login and signup components are wrapped by a modal component.

```
@Component({
  template: `<app-login></app-login>`
})
export class LoginModalComponent { .. whatever in here, maybe something useful .. }
```

then your service would instantiate the `LoginModalComponent`

```
this.loginModalRef = this.dialog.open(LoginModalComponent, {panelClass: 'login-dialog'});
```

this avoids the circular dependency of LoginComponent -> AuthService and AuthService -> LoginComponent,

now its LoginModalComponent -> AuthService -> LoginComponent

the wrapper component can likely also take some of the logic inside your login component for better modularity.

another option is a sort of remote service that gets injected into auth service and the login component

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalRemoteService {
  private closeLoginSource = new Subject();
  closeLogin$ = this.closeLoginSource.asObservable();
  private openLoginSource = new Subject();
  openLogin$ = this.openLoginSource.asObservable();

  closeLoginModal(): void {
    this.closeLoginSource.next();
  }

  openLoginModal(): void {
    this.openLoginSource.next();
  }
}
```

and auth service subscrsibes to these signals and login / signup component triggers them, this way you no longer need to inject auth into login.

You generally have a structural issue where you're using a service to instantiate and destroy components from within the components that you must solve somehow.  generally with wrappers or remotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first approach worked like a charm. For anybody who's facing the same problem, don't forget to change your entry components to the new created modal components. I first tried the 2nd approach but somehow stuck because I didn't quite understand how that would work. Just to clarify, I need to inject the authservice into login and signup, because I have all the other logic there. Also, I'm triggering the modals from many different places, like the auth-guard for example. How exactly does the 2nd approach work? can you ellaborate?